# RecyclerAdapter IndexOutOfBoundError on using CustomViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

What i'm trying to do is that, I have an adapter which I'm using for many different activities each having their own ViewHolder. So I'm firstly making an abstract recycler adapter named DimRecyclerAbstractAdapter without a ViewHolder. Then for each different activity I'm making a static inner class named DimCustomAdapter which extends DimRecyclerAbstractAdapter having it's own ViewHolder. But I'm getting this error.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                                                                                     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
```

This is the abstract adapter class  -

```
public abstract class DimRecyclerAbstractAdapter<VHA extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VHA> {

    private List<tbl_dim_1> mtbldimList1;

    public DimRecyclerAbstractAdapter(List<tbl_dim_1> tblDimList1) {
        this.mtbldimList1 = tblDimList1;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
            return mtbldimList1.size();
    }

    public void addItems(List<tbl_dim_1> tblDimList1) {

        this.mtbldimList1 = tblDimList1;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mtbldimList1 = null;
        super.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

}
```

This is the activity in which I've implemented custom ViewHolder -

```
public class DetailActivity1 extends LifecycleActivity{

    DimListViewModel dmvmodel;
    RecyclerView rcView;
    DimCustomAdapter rcAdapter;
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "In DetailActivity1 ";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recycler_view);

        Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
        int rid_int = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("mRId",0);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Rid value int == " + rid_int);

        rcView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        rcAdapter = new DimCustomAdapter(new ArrayList<tbl_dim_1>());
        rcView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(DetailActivity1.this));
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Layout manager set");
        rcView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);

        dmvmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DimListViewModel.class);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "View model returned");


        dmvmodel.getDimList2con1(rid_int).observe(DetailActivity1.this, new Observer<List<tbl_dim_1>>() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<tbl_dim_1> changedItems) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onChanged called, items will be added");
                rcAdapter.addItems(changedItems);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        rcAdapter = null;
        rcView.setAdapter(null);
        rcView.setLayoutManager(null);
        rcView = null;
        dmvmodel = null;
        super.onDestroy();
        RefWatcher refWatcher = LeakCheckApplication.getRefWatcher(this);
        refWatcher.watch(this);
    }

    public static class DimCustomAdapter extends DimRecyclerAbstractAdapter<DimCustomAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

        private static List<tbl_dim_1> mtbldimCustom;

        DimCustomAdapter(List<tbl_dim_1> tblDimListPassed) {
            super(mtbldimCustom);
            mtbldimCustom = tblDimListPassed;
        }

        @Override
        public DimCustomAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View vw = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);

//          vw.setOnClickListener(vwOnClickListener);
            return new DimCustomAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder(vw);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
//          Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Inside onBindViewHolder - ");
            if (holder.dataTextView.getText() != null) {
                String LOG_TAG = "DimCustomAdapter:";
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "holder is not null, i was right");
                holder.dataTextView.setText(null);
                holder.dataTextView.setOnClickListener(null);
            }

            final tbl_dim_1 dimAtPosition = mtbldimCustom.get(position);
            holder.dataTextView.setText(dimAtPosition.mCONTENT);
            holder.dataTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg) {

                    Intent dw = new Intent(arg.getContext(), DetailActivity2.class);
                    dw.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    dw.putExtra("mRId", dimAtPosition.mR_ID);
                    arg.getContext().startActivity(dw);
                }
            });
        }

        class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private TextView dataTextView;

            RecyclerViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                dataTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data_text_view);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm calling this inner class from outer class within same activity -

```
DimCustomAdapter rcAdapter = new DimCustomAdapter(new ArrayList<tbl_dim_1>());
```

Comment: show your Activity. problem coming from `new ArrayList<tbl_dim_1>()`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Please see me updated question

Answer (score 1):

Its because of empty list that you are passing while creating the adapter.
DimCustomAdapter rcAdapter = new DimCustomAdapter(`new ArrayList<tbl_dim_1>()`);

Just add a null or empty check in `onBindViewHolder` method before calling

```
final tbl_dim_1 dimAtPosition = mtbldimCustom.get(position);
```

Hope this will stop crashing your application.

You can try like below,

```
ArrayList<tbl_dim_1> list = new ArrayList<>()
rcAdapter = new DimCustomAdapter(list);
```

then in observe method,

```
dmvmodel.getDimList2con1(rid_int).observe(DetailActivity1.this, new Observer<List<tbl_dim_1>>() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<tbl_dim_1> changedItems) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onChanged called, items will be added");
                list.addAll(changedItems);
                rcAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Durga_M I enclosed the emthod body of onBindViewHolder by this null check -   " if(mtbldimCustom != null) " but still getting same error -

Comment: Add empty check.  if(!mtbldimCustom.isEmpty())

Comment: Ok, Now I'm not getting the previous error but a new error -                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.example.priyanshu.importsql/com.example.priyanshu.importsql.dimdetail.DetailActivity1}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.isEmpty()' on a null object reference

Comment: Now I'm getting an empty recyclerview with no data in it, also the clicks aren't working (DetailActivity1 is the activity I've posted in question)

Comment: Empty recylcerview as your list does not have any data. Make sure your list has data to display in the recycler view.

Comment: Firstly I'm passing an empty arraylist then after attching an observer to the recyclerview I'm passing the livedata in it( fetching data through viewmodel) using addItems() method in DimRecyclerAbstractAdapter

Comment: your edited answer gave this error -                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.isEmpty()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution i worked out for my problem( In case anyone face the same problem ). 
Modyfying Durga's answer -

1. Firstly i added the isEmpty() check that he mentioned in comment.
2. Then in the activity i changed the code to this -

a) Added this new method in DimCustomAdapter -

```
public void changeList(List<tbl_dim_1> addedList){
            mtbldimCustom = addedList;
        }
```

b) Called this method in observe method -

```
dmvmodel.getDimList2con1(rid_int).observe(DetailActivity1.this, new Observer<List<tbl_dim_1>>() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<tbl_dim_1> changedItems) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onChanged called, items will be added");
                rcAdapter.changeList(changedItems);
                rcAdapter.addItems(changedItems);
            }
        });
```